# Composition series for dihedral grup of order $2pq^2$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

Let $p,q$ be different primes and $D_{2pq^2}=\langle ab\mid a^{pq^2}=b^2=1, ba=a^{-1}b\rangle$ the dihedral group of order $2pq^2$. Find a composition series for $D_{2pq^2}$.

I don't know how to start this question. First, I have to find a maximal normal subgroup right? How can I do that? And how to proceed?

Comment: What are you studying?
What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: I found this question in an sample exam for comprehensive exams. So probably I can use everything from group theory that you should know after a Bachelor Degree. But I personally don't know much about the dihedral groups, so as basic as possible would be nice. I was thinking about using Sylow's Theorems to find a normal subgroup? But didn't suceeded

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Dihedral Groups](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can go step by step to construct a composition series.

It's easy to see that $\langle a \rangle$ is a maximal subgroup. It's order is $pq^2$, so it's index is $2$ and thus $\frac{D_{2pq^2}}{\langle a \rangle}$ is a simple group, which is enough to conclude that $\langle a \rangle $ is a maximal normal subgroup.

Now work in $\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq^2}$. It is a cyclic group and thus the existence of subgroup of any order dividing $pq^2$ is guaranteed. For example you can take the subgroup $\langle a^p \rangle$ of order $q^2$ and index $p$. As it's quotent is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, simple group it's maximal normal subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$

Now simialrly $\langle a^{pq} \rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $\langle a^{p} \rangle$. Finally $\langle a^{pq} \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_q$, which is a simple subgroup, so the composition series terminates with the trivial subgroup. Therefore we end up with the following composition series

$$\langle e \rangle \lhd \langle a^{pq} \rangle \lhd \langle a^{p} \rangle \lhd \langle a \rangle \lhd D_{2pq^2}$$